# Bluetooth LE Connection in Ionic-React with Capacitor-community Bluetooth-LE plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic-react, capacitor-plugin

I am developing an android app using Ionic-React that scan the BLE devices and connect to the device.

I am using capacitor community Bluetooth LE plugin [github](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le) for the purpose,
I am able to scan and connect to Bluetooth Low Energy device but, the connection status is not updating on the BLE device.

Please do help, I have raised this issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le/issues/141), but no response.

Hope I get the solution.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am learning Ionic React myself and am really struggling with how to use BluetoothLE in my app. Any chance we could chat privately? Perhaps you could give me some tips for getting started... Thanks.

Comment: @PhillHealey: have you succeeded? If yes, could you share how you managed to do it please?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was a coding issue since the connection was established and but the state was not being shared between pages. Since states are only persistent within the same page, this is normal behaviour. To get around that I needed to use https://jotai.org/ for a shared persistent state.